# Using SFINAE with wrappers to terminate compilation early

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

### The Goal

Provide some wrappers to a C++11 template library's main entry point so that if the initial template parameter is not valid, the user is informed of exactly what is missing.

In the real library, each `class Device` is actually a `template <class Projection> class SomeDevice {/* ... */ };`, and each `Projection` class has about 10 `static constexpr` definitions used throughout.  If a user has a bad `Projection`, I'd like to tell them this before hundreds of compiler errors fly across the screen using `static_assert`.

Wielding SFINAE is new to me, and in the research I became most attached to [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).  Since this is a C++11 project (by necessity, dependencies...):

### Question 1: is it safe to just define `void_t` myself?

```
#include <iostream>  // question split into parts, copy
#include <type_traits>// paste top to bottom for MWE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SFINAE setup
//<<< Q1 (a) >>>
namespace internal { template< class... > using void_t = void; }

//<<< Q1 (b) >>> [would also be in `namespace internal`
// template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
// template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

// primary template handles types that have no nested ::my_def member:
template< class, class = internal::void_t<> >
struct has_my_def : std::false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a nested ::my_def member:
template< class T >
struct has_my_def<T, internal::void_t<typename T::my_def>> : std::true_type { };
```

Though many other options exist, this is my favorite.  The definition of `std::void_t` both in the link, as well as checking the actual `type_traits` headers seems foolproof.  **Is there any danger** in using `(a)`?  The linked article mentioned `(b)`, but the actual reason for it was well beyond my understanding.

### Question 2: choosing how to design the wrapper -- struct or function?

Regardless of the actual definition of `has_my_def` (the `void_t` approach, `typedef char yes[1]; typedef char no[2] ...`), is there any reason to use a wrapper struct over an overloaded (right term?) function?

- #### 2(a) -- Struct approach:

  ```
  namespace internal {
      template <class Device, bool valid>
      struct proxy {
          static int execute() {
              // if straight `false`, will always fail. I am
              // worried that some compilers might see "oh <true>
              // is specialized, so `valid` must be `false`"
              //            vvvvv
              static_assert(valid, "You have been asserted.");
              return 1;
          }
      };

      template <class Device>
      struct proxy<Device, true> {
          static int execute() {
              std::cout << "Do some stuff" << std::endl;
              return 0;
          }
      };
  }

  // this would be the "main entry point"
  template <class Device>
  int execute() {
      return internal::proxy<Device, has_my_def<Device>::value>::execute();
  }
  ```
- #### 2(b) -- Function approach

  ```
  template <class Device>
  typename std::enable_if< !has_my_def<Device>::value, int>::type
  alt_execute() {
      // but if `valid` above got inferred, would the same not
      // be so for  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ?
      static_assert(has_my_def<Device>::value, "You have been asserted.");
      return 1;
  }

  template <class Device>
  typename std::enable_if< has_my_def<Device>::value, int>::type
  alt_execute() {
      std::cout << "Work gets done." << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

#### Simple main if desired

```
struct Good { using my_def = float; };
struct Bad {};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    // sanity checks
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "Good: " << has_my_def<Good>::value << std::endl
              << "Bad:  " << has_my_def<Bad>::value  << std::endl;

    // good
    int g1 = execute<Good>();
    int g2 = alt_execute<Good>();

    int b1 = 0, b2 = 0;
    // fail :) uncomment one or the other, if both
    // uncommented, only b1 gets compiled (goal)
    // b1 = execute<Bad>();
    b2 = alt_execute<Bad>();

    return g1 + g2 + b1 + b2;// -Wno-unused-variable ;)
}
```

#### The "dilemma"

I don't really know which approach to use, or if I am missing something obvious.  I tend to want to lean toward the function approach because, since I need to check about 10 more nested types of `my_def`, I was thinking it would be possible to write one 10 parameter function where the static assert just says "here are all the things you need", instead of writing a macro to generate 10 structs.

Any thoughts are appreciated, I think understanding best practices here is really important!